# Should non-nullable entity properties be nullable type in PHP?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Using Symfony 6.1, I have this Entity:

```php
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: InvoiceRepository::class)]
class Invoice implements SearchableEntityInterface
{

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private int $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'datetime')]
    private DateTimeInterface $timeCreated;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'datetime', nullable: true)]
    private ?DateTimeInterface $timePaid = null;

    // ...
}
```

The only nullable field in DB is `timePaid`, the rest is required to be NOT NULL in DB.

My code reflects "nullability" of DB in PHP code, i.e. if the field can be NULL in DB, then its nullable in PHP, but never otherwise.

However when using the `make:entity` or checking online examples you always see

```php
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private ?int $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'datetime')]
    private ?DateTimeInterface $timeCreated;
```

i.e. nullable PHP properties even when it CANNOT be null ever.

**Is it correct to declare ID field and non-nullable fields as non-nullable in PHP? Can there be any issues from this approach?**

Comment: There are different schools of thought on that subject. Some will prefer to have their entities always in a valid state (and leveraging DTO extensively). Others will prefer simplicity and make these properties nullable even though it is not nullable in the database.

Comment: I think [this issue](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/issues/1175) is relevant, too, as it related to maker specifically: "_This was done on purpose as a way to add types still be as friendly as possible to user._"

Comment: One annoying problem with non-nullable properties is that forms will often end up posting empty data as null.  There is a form setting that helps.  Or you might need to adjust your setter methods to accept a null and then transform it into an empty value.  It's the sort of thing you just need to try and see if the extra effort is worth it for your particular entities.